# An application of Liapunov's Condition with a parameter restriction

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

> Let $\{X_{i}\}_{i\geq1}$ be a collection of independent r.v's with probabilities 
>   $$\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=n^{\alpha})=\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=-n^{\alpha})=\frac{1}{2}$$
>   Show that the CLT is valid as long as $\alpha > -\frac{1}{2}$.

We know that $\mathbb{E}(X_{n}) = 0, \quad \mathbb{E}(X_{n}^{2}) = n^{2\alpha}, \quad\mathbb{E}(|X_{n}|^{2+\delta}) = n^{\alpha(2+\delta)}$.

By the Liapunov condition we get the following:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(|X_{k}-\mu_{k}|^{2+\delta})}{((\mathbb{Var}X_{n})^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2+\delta}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\alpha(2+\delta)}}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2\alpha}\right)^{\frac{2+\delta}{2}}}$$
Why can't $\alpha < -\frac{1}{2}$? I don't see it clearly, sorry if it is a simple question and thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p$ is well approximated by the integral $\int_0^n x^p\,dx=n^{p+1}/(p+1)$. This should allow you determine when there exists a $\delta>0$ for which the fraction converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geqslant 2$ and $p\gt -1$, the following inequalities hold:
$$
c_pn^{p+1}   \leqslant\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n k^p\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n k^p\leqslant C_p n^{p+1}
$$
hence for $\alpha>-1/2$, there exists constants $C_\delta$ and $C'_\delta$ such that 
$$
C_\delta n^{\alpha(2+\delta)+1-\frac{2+\delta}2\left(2\alpha+1\right)}\leqslant \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(|X_{k}-\mu_{k}|^{2+\delta})}{((\mathbb{Var}X_{n})^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2+\delta}}\leqslant C'_\delta n^{\alpha(2+\delta)+1-\frac{2+\delta}2\left(2\alpha+1\right)}.
$$
Since 
$$
\alpha(2+\delta)+1-\frac{2+\delta}2\left(2\alpha+1\right)=-\delta/2,
$$
Lyapunov's condition holds.

For $\alpha\leqslant -1/2$, this does not apply since the series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k^{2\alpha}$ converges.